# Integrate Elasticsearch with Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring-mvc, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-jdbc-river

How to Integrate Elasticsearch with Spring MVC application and perform basic CRUD Operations.

Comment: I think this post might help: Spring MVC with elasticsearch http://blog.trifork.com/2014/04/15/elasticsearch-spring-mvc-sencha-touch-2-in-the-cloud-part-1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe [this](https://github.com/dadoonet/spring-elasticsearch/) can help you or perhaps [this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch)? I hope this will lead you closer to what you want.